# Solving matrix equation involving products of powers of $(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How to solve for $\mathbf{X}$ the following equation

$$\mathbf{A} = a (b\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1/2} (c\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}) (b\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1/2}$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest that you do the $1\times 1$ case first.

Comment: @ancientmathematician the $1 \times 1$ case is trivial since there the product commutative property applies.

Comment: And what's not commutative in your problem?

Comment: @ancientmathematician The matrix product is not commutative in the equation, preventing to group the two $(b\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1/2}$ that are pre- and post-multiplying.

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, then you have that $-c$ is an eigenvalue of $X$, moreover, $-b$ is not since $bI+X$ is invertible

Comment: I think that if the $-\frac{1}{2}$ powers make sense  then everything commutes.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I dont fully understand your comment. Note that even if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are hermitian positive definite matrices $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B} \neq \mathbf{A}^{-1/2}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{-1/2}$, so they do not commute.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif It may be assumed that $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible and non-trivial.

Comment: I still can't see why everything is not in the commutative ring of the Laurent series in $\mathbf{X}$

Comment: Assume your notation makes sense, and $X=V^{-1}\Lambda V$ is the canonical form, where $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n)$. Then for any polynomial (moreover, for convergent power series) $f$, $f(X)=V^{-1}f(\Lambda) V$. By this, you simplify the problem of "function of matrix" into "function of $\lambda$", which gives you commutativity on the right hand side.

Comment: @Fan That might be used to extract the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $\mathbf{X}$ but what about its eigenvectors? Without them $\mathbf{X}$ might not be constructed...

Comment: I am not quite sure what your question means. By eigenvectors, do you mean the matrix $V$ above? It does not matter as the point is just to prove commutativity. Or you can try write everything down (use $f=(1+x)^{-1/2}=1-x/2+\cdots$), and you will see that $V$ will be used to get $X$ back.

Comment: But wait, $X$ can only be similar to a triangular matrix and not diagonal, so, I don't see what's the point of assuming something that's not generally correct.

Comment: Yes my description is not rigorous, it is just to give the general idea. It is not hard to generalize if you can see the general Jordan form is just $\Lambda+J$ with $J^m=0$ for some $m$.

Comment: Also to explain what @ancientmathematician possibly wanted to say, $I$ and $X$ generates an algebra $L$ over $\mathbb{C}$, which is obviously commutative. In a non rigorous way, the closure $L'$ of the algebra is still commutative. And $(bI+X)^{-1/2}$ is a limit point in $L$, which lies in $L'$ and thus commutes with $(cI+X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U^{1/2}=\exp(1/2 \log(U))$. But, what is this $\log$ ? And is $U^{1/2}$ a polynomial in $U$ ? That depends on the definition of the above $\log$. In particular, the question is badly written.

Everything works well when we assume that $U$ has no eigenvalues in $]-\infty,0]$ and we choose the principal $\log$. Then $\log(U)$ and, consequently, $U^{1/2}$ and $U^{-1/2}=({U^{1/2}})^{-1}$ are polynomials in $U$. They are primary matrix functions (cf. Higham, functions of matrices). More over $(A^{1/2})^2=A$. We assume that we are in the above situation.

Here the hypothesis about $X$ is: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X$, then $b+\lambda\notin ]-\infty,0]$. Finally $A$ is a polynomial in $X$ and $AX=XA$. then the equation can be rewritten:

$$(bI+X)A=a(cI+X),\text{ or }X(A-aI)=acI-bA,$$
 that is elementary.